# Limit of $f(x)=x/|x|$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> Consider the function $f$ defined in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ by $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

My attempt:

Note that $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.

Suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ exists.

Applying the definition with $\varepsilon =1$, there should be $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<1.$$

Taking $x=\delta/2$, implies $|1-L|<1$, then $-1<-1-L<1$, which implies $1-L<1\iff 0<L$

Now, taking $x=-\delta/2$ implies $|-1-L|<1,$ then $-1<-1-L<1,$ which implies $-1<-1-L\iff L<0$. (Contradiction)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first observation for right and left limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{|x|}=1 \neq \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x}{|x|}=-1 $$

suffices to prove that the limit at $x=0$ doesn't exist by [uniqueness theorem for limits](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-uniqueness-of-limits-of-a-function-theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is signum function.
$$f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$$ is its identical twin.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the contradiction in one fell swoop from the strict inequality step in

$$\begin{align}
2&=|1-(-1)|\\
&=|f(\delta/2)-f(-\delta/2)|\\
&=|(f(\delta/2)-L)+(L-f(-\delta/2))|\\
&\le|f(\delta/2)-L|+|L-f(-\delta/2)|\\
&\lt1+1\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

where the key step invokes the triangle inequality $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$.